# remote TeamViewer is not visible - how to connect to remote computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, teamviewer

last night I bought and installed a 27" samsung monitor in order to use teamviewer with plenty of space.

Before I installed the new hardware I was connecting to my patner computer without any problem.

After the installation, I could no longer connect. I doubt the teamviewer application has anything to do with my new monitor, but I am struggling to find the causes.

Here is how I connect:
[image]

I get authentication rejected:

[image]

when I look at the logs:

[image]

[Here you can find the complete log for this failure.](https://gist.github.com/jjradha/33da769204e5855bcc92ccab68f114b8)

But just to summarise the reason is said to be:

> CLogin::AuthenticateClient() Connection to 419600239 denied, because
>   remote TeamViewer is not visible

how to troubleshoot this issue?
what is causing it?

Soon I will be in the building where the other computer is located, is there any settings I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what has caused it**

Arrive at the building where the target computer is,
the screen resolution had mirrored that of my computer at home, and what used to be screen number 1 was the screen number 2 and vice versa.

Also because I thought the problem was related to authentication I wrongly decided the change my password when trying to establish connection.

In a summary, the TeamViewer was not responding, and I guess that was the main reason I could not connect.

Now after sorting out the screens and rebooting the machine I tried to connect from here to home and it was successful.

> Something else to look out for is using different versions of Team
>   Viewer from the the side you're connecting to and connecting from...
>   I've been bit by that issue before. – [McDonald's](https://superuser.com/users/510662/mcdonalds)